# Convert PDF file to binary: Node JS and Express

Tags: node.js, express, binary

I have an application that uploads PDF file and then the file has to be converted into Binary (in the backend without saving the file in a temp folder) to store it in a database.

I am being able to upload the file and read the data, however, I am not being able to convert it to binary.

Following is my`app.js`

```
var upload = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(upload());
function upload_file(req, res, next) {
    console.log('here');
    if (!req.files) {
        res.send({
            status: false,
            message: 'No file uploaded'
        });
    }else if (req.method == "POST") {
        console.log('here');
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        console.log(form);
        let file = req.files.fileToUpload;
        console.log(file);
        }
    }
```

The output of the function once a pdf file has been uploaded is:
[image]

I tried `const encoded = req.files.fileToUpload.buffer.toString('base64');` and I get an error.
I also tried `fs.readFileSync` but since I'm not storing the file locally, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload#usage), `req.files.fileToUpload.data` should contain the file's data in a buffer:

> req.files.foo.data: A buffer representation of your file, returns
> empty buffer in case useTempFiles option was set to true.

So you should be able to use `data` and further process this buffer.

Comment: I tried ```req.files.fileToUpload.data``` and I'm able to extract the data, but I'm still not being able to convert it to binary

Comment: Not sure I understand correcty - the buffer already contains the raw bytes?

Comment: Or are you talking about converting it to `base64` as you tried? Then the title of the question would be misleading :)

Comment: I'm getting the data in bytes and I want to convert it to ```binary```.

Comment: You may want to check out this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42847603/3761628
Although you should not need to create a new binary-buffer as you already have the buffer.